# Substitute text markers with text from columns with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to replace text markers with certain text that is ordered in a column.

[image]

In column `Tried...`, I am using the below `RandCell` function to get a random cell from a range of cells:

```
Function RandCell(Rg As range, columnRange As range, headerRange As range) As Variant
    'Dim rplc
    Dim textRange

    'get random cell
    RandCell = Rg.Cells(Int(Rnd * Rg.Cells.Count) + 1)
    'find column to replace
'    rplc = RandCell.Find(headerRange)

End Function
```

In the column `Wanted`, I am using the following formular to `substitute` the values: `=IF(COUNTIF(E3;"*"&$C$2&"*");SUBSTITUTE(E3;$C$2;C3);SUBSTITUTE(E3;$D$2;D3))`

However, if I have more than 10 rows this solution is extremely awkward. Hence, I was thinking of implementing a function in vba.

As indicated above I tried to implement the functionality into the `RandCell` function. However, I am extremely new to vba and kindly ask you for your input!

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**

Below you can see an example.:

[image]

First, a random text is choosen. Then for example in `E3` the text marker in the random text is replaced by the value in `C` or `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like:

[image]

in cols **A**, **B**, and **D**, the following macro:

```
Sub mrquad()
    Dim L As Long, M As Long, N As Long, Kount As Long
    Dim v1F As String, v1L As String

    Kount = 10

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        L = .CountA(Range("A:A")) - 1
        M = .CountA(Range("C:C")) - 1
        N = .CountA(Range("D:D")) - 1
        For kk = 1 To Kount
            v1 = Cells(.RandBetween(3, L + 2), "A").Value
            v1F = Left(v1, Len(v1) - 3)
            v1L = Right(v1, 3)
            If v1L = "[1]" Then
                v2 = Cells(.RandBetween(3, M + 2), "C").Value
            Else
                v2 = Cells(.RandBetween(3, N + 2), "d").Value
            End If
            Cells(kk, "F").Value = v1F & v2
        Next kk
    End With
End Sub
```

will pick ***10*** samples at random from column **A** and, depending on the suffix, pick a random replacement suffix from either column **C** or column **D** and place the result in column **F**:

[image]

The number of sample is determined by the `Kount` variable. The spaces in cols **C** or **D** are single spaces rather than empties.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! However, your answer does not fully solve my problem. I would love to have a function so that I get, in F3 (in your posted picture), when a random value from column `A` appears, such as `whatever [1]`, the `[1]` is replaced by the the value `47` in row `[1]`. If a random value with `[2]` in it appears, `h1` is used.

Comment: @mrquad  I don't understand.

Comment: Please see also my above update. I also aI tried to clarify above again. I also added a picture.